# Code block inside list is too close to above paragraph if a paragraph does not follow it

Tags: bug, design, markdown, markdown-rendering

**Good**: paragraph `p2` follows:

- Item 1. Block below nicely separated from this text:

  ```
  block
  ```

  p2
- item 2

Code:

```
-   Item 1. Block below nicely separated from this text:

        block

    p2

-   item 2
```

**Bad**: removed `p2` from above:

- Item 1. Block below is too close to this text:

  ```
  block
  ```
- item 2

Code:

```
-   Item 1. Block below is too close to this text:

        block

-   item 2
```

I was too lazy to investigate the CSS further.

Tested on Firefox 46, Ubuntu 15.10.

Not present on Android app 1.0.85.

[Web archive for future generations](https://web.archive.org/web/20160427193815/https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321939/code-block-inside-list-is-too-close-to-abov-paragraph-if-a-paragraph-does-not-fo).

Comment: I just came across [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36926431/3266847), and if there is inline code in the line before the code block, it looks extra horrible as the grey backgrounds touch: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/LG3LXX1.png)

Answer (score 3):

As vol7ron mentions, there is a `p:last-of-type` rule that's zeroing out the margin on any `p` that's the last within its parent in the context of a `ul, ol`, for whatever reason:

```css
.post-text ul p:last-of-type, .wmd-preview ul p:last-of-type, .post-text ol p:last-of-type, .wmd-preview ol p:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

One proposed fix is to just get rid of that rule altogether. It seems to have been put in place to prevent doubled vertical margins between the last `p` and its parent `li`, but CSS already has a mechanism for preventing that and it's called margin collapse. See my answer to [this question on the main site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033299/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-css-shorthand-for-all-elements-except-the-first-l/10033333#10033333) (specifically, the last paragraph).

If the margins between the `p` and its parent `li` are not equal, and the rule was put in place to ensure the `li` margin always takes precedence even if it is smaller than that of `p`, the selector-list should be changed to:

```css
.post-text ul > li > p:last-child, .wmd-preview ul > li > p:last-child, .post-text ol > li > p:last-child, .wmd-preview ol > li > p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

to prevent the rule from affecting

1. `p` elements whose margins would not be collapsing with the `li` *anyway*, and
2. other, completely unrelated `p` elements within the `ul, ol`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a couple of `<br>`s at the end of item 1 to workaround.

**Workaround**:

- Item 1. Block below is nicely separated from this text:

  ```
  block
  ```
- item 2

Code

```
-   Item 1. Block below is nicely separated from this text:<br><br>

        block

-   item 2
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Looks Fine to Me

- list

  ```
  code
  ```
- list

  ```
  code
  ```

---

#### Too Much Space Using `<br><br>`

- list

  ```
  code
  ```
- list

  ```
  code
  ```

---

The culprit is more than likely this line in the CSS, which removes the bottom-margin spacing under certain paragraphs:

```
.post-text ul p:last-of-type, .wmd-preview ul p:last-of-type, .post-text ol p:last-of-type, .wmd-preview ol p:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

It looks like every paragraph is being treated as last-of-type, so the CSS is probably not styling as it was intended.

Comment: But it didn't use to be that close, did it? It's too close to the text for my taste. It should always have the same distance as it has when there is a paragraph after the code block.

Comment: Yeah I think it was just like the second before, but all I'm saying is I'm not complaining :)  I like the code being closer to the description.  My preference would be a mixture of the two, about half the space of a line break.

Comment: @Benjamin [This screenshot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99651/234299) suggests that there used to be more space, which is also what I remember.

Comment: Also consider when `list` is inline code `\`list\``. The gray areas touch one another.

Comment: Either they fixed it or this does not look like it happens on mobile

Comment: @vol7ron not present on android app, not fixed on Firefox. Added to question.